# Create object with name to inject into unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, autofixture

I'm unit testing a class that takes a factory as one of it's dependencies and uses this to build objects that the `SUT` effectively controls:

```
class SystemUnderTest
{
    private readonly IFoo foo1;

    private readonly IFoo foo2;

    public SystemUnderTest(IFooFactory fooFactory)
    {
        this.foo1 = fooFactory.Build("Bar1");
        this.foo2 = fooFactory.Build("Bar2");
    }

    public IFoo Foo1
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.foo1;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The `SystemUnderTest` object has a singleton lifetime that is injected into multiple `ViewModels` that use it's properties/method to perform different actions, so this effectively rules out defining a `Provider` class so that I could inject `foo1` and `foo2` without interfacing with the factory within the constructor which is what I would normally do when facing this issue.

But by injecting the factory I am unable to figure out with `AutoFixture` how I could correctly configure the `fooFactory` to provide the correct `IFoo` and pass this as a method parameter into my test such as:

```
[Theory]
[AutoData]
internal void Foo1_IsCorrectlyPopulated_Test(
    [Frozen] IFoo foo1,
    SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest)
{
    var actual = systemUnderTest.Foo1;

    Assert.Same(foo1, actual);
}
```

I understand that I can extend the `AutoData` attribute and provide my own customization to the Fixture such as:

```
class SystemUnderTestAutoDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public SystemUnderTestAutoData()
    {
        var fooFactory = this.Fixture.Freeze<IFooFactory>();
        var foo1 = this.Fixture.Create<IFoo>();

        Mock.Get(fooFactory).Setup(m => m.Build("Bar1")).Returns(foo1);
    }
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is the ability to get the `foo1` object that I created within the attribute constructor and have this passed into the test method as a parameter? I understand that I could `Freeze` the `foo1` object but this means that I would need to have two attribute classes for `foo1` and `foo2` to supply the correct information to my test method and this falls over when I have to use both objects within my test case.

I was hoping that there was a way that I could create the object with a particular name (or some other matching method) and match that within the test case like (does not compile):

```
[Theory]
[SystemUnderTestAutoData]
internal void Foo1_IsCorrectlyPopulated_Test(
    [Frozen(Matching.CreationName)] IFoo foo1,
    SystemUnderTest systemUnderTest)
{
    ...
}

class SystemUnderTestAutoDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public SystemUnderTestAutoData()
    {
        var fooFactory = this.Fixture.Freeze<IFooFactory>();
        var foo1 = this.Fixture.Create<IFoo>(creationName: @"foo1");

        Mock.Get(fooFactory).Setup(m => m.Build("Bar1")).Returns(foo1);
    }
}
```

So that any matching registered instances with the name (or some other matching method) can be resolved as part of the test case parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should work. First, define an `[AutoMoqData]` attribute like this:

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

Second, write your test like this:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void MyTest([Frozen]Mock<IFooFactory> td, IFoo foo1, IFoo foo2, IFixture fixture)
{
    td.Setup(f => f.Build("Bar1")).Returns(foo1);
    td.Setup(f => f.Build("Bar2")).Returns(foo2);
    var sut = fixture.Create<SystemUnderTest>();

    // Rest of test...
}
```

That said, using factories to deal with lifetime issues is almost always a design smell. The particular design in the OP violates [Nikola Malovic's 4th law of IoC](https://vuscode.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/inversion-of-control-single-responsibility-principle-and-nikola-s-laws-of-dependency-injection). Consider separating the design of your objects from their lifetime management. One way to do that could be with a [Decoraptor](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/08/24/decoraptor/).

Comment: Thanks Mark I thought that may be the easiest way but I wanted to see if there was something that would enable to not have to manually create the `SUT` in the test, but this is fine. In terms of design I understand that this is a smell, but I struggle to see how a `Decoraptor` would assist in this instance, in that both my `Client (ViewModel)` and `Service` effectively have Singleton lifetimes, since the service in my case stores state which whenever this state was accessed would require a reconstruction of the service each time?

Comment: @StephenRoss That's a new question ;)